# Why I can't update the source rpm?

Tags: yum, rpm

I have following 2 packages installed on a Redhat Enterprise 7.0 instance

```
bind-license-9.9.4-14.el7_0.1.noarch
bind-libs-lite-9.9.4-14.el7_0.1.x86_64
```

The "repoquery -i" command tells me that the source rpm of these packages is bind.

```
repoquery -i bind-license-9.9.4-14.el7_0.1.noarch

Name        : bind-license
Version     : 9.9.4
Release     : 14.el7_0.1
Architecture: noarch
Size        : 26019
Packager    : Red Hat, Inc. <http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla>
Group       : Applications/System
URL         : http://www.isc.org/products/BIND/
Repository  : rhel-7-server-rpms
Summary     : License of the BIND DNS suite
Source      : **bind-9.9.4-14.el7_0.1.src.rpm**
Description :
Contains license of the BIND DNS suite.
Similarly if I use the yum downloader to download the source rpms of above 2     packages the bind source rpm (bind-9.9.4-14.el7_0.1.src.rpm) is downloaded.
```

However if we try to update the bind here is what I get

```
yum update bind
Loaded plugins: product-id, subscription-manager
Package(s) bind available, but not installed.
**No packages marked for update**
```

My question is why are repoquery and yumdownloader reporting bind-9.9.4-14.el7_0.1.src.rpm as the source rpm. If bind is the correct source rpm then why is "yum update bind" saying that the bind is not installed on the system?

Answer (score 1):

A source rpm can create one or more binary rpms.  Unless you are building your own binary rpms, you don't need to worry about the source rpm.   So repoquery is showing you that bind-9.9.4-14.el7_0.1.src.rpm is the source rpm for bind-license.  That same source rpm creates bind, bind-libs, bind-license, bind-utils (and many more).

Answer (score 0):

`repoquery` will query a repository, that means a remote server which stores a bunch of RPM, and tell you some informations about it (ie: files included in this RPM). `repoquery` doesn't care if the package you are requesting is installed on your system unless you add the `--installed` flag.

I guess the command you typed will output nothing if you add this flag:

```
repoquery --installed -i bind-license-9.9.4-14.el7_0.1.noarch
```

So actually, `Bind` is not installed on your system. To list packages actually installed, you can try one of the following:

```
repoquery --installed -a
```

or

```
yum list installed
```

Comment: As per output of  “yum list” and “repoquery --installed -a” the bind-libs and bind-license are really installed in the system. I want to know the source rpms of these packages.

Comment: If i use the “repoquery -i bind-license-9.9.4-14.el7_0.1.noarch” as mentioned in my question then the source rpm listed is bind-9.9.4-14.el7_0.1.src.rpm

This is where i get confused. See the source rpm of bind-license is bind and bind is not even installed in the system.